# Format code and include line numbers in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, formatting

I want to paste Android code both Java and XML into MS-Word. However the formatted code especially the line numbers are affected by the XML declarations. So some of my line numers are in black, others in orange.

Is there an alternative method to use apart from exporting RTF code from Notepad++ as mentioned in this post: [Formatting code with line numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/378996/formatting-code-with-line-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Use http://hilite.me/. If you can't paste special in your version of word, save the code as HTML and insert it as a file.

http://quickhighlighter.com/ should also work.